# How to wire 240v wall oven with only 3 wire (L1, N, PE)

Tags: wiring, 240v, oven

Bought a house (in Canada) that came with a replacement wall oven. Getting ready to install and ran into a snag. There is only 3 wires (L1, N PE).
Oven is an Electrolux EI24EW45LS 240v 60 Hz. Every search I'm not finding much with just those 3 hookups. #4 and #5 along with a ground are the lugs at the back of the oven before it goes to the wire. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Picture album link.](https://ibb.co/album/KmZS8k)

From the wall to the original oven in the house, has a 4 prong 3 wire red black white plus copper for ground.

Comment: how have you deterrmined that the white wire is neutral?

Comment: Calling it "PE" indicates to me that you're not in the US, but 60Hz indicates that you are - please indicate where in the world you are located, as that does matter. Does the oven need 120v to power anything like clocks, lights or other circuitry?

Comment: In the US if an appliance does not need to have 120v, then quite often the white wire can be marked as a second hot.  If the appliance does need to have 120v, then the white wire must be used for neutral.  This usually requires the replacement of the cable or a second hot wire pull though conduit.

Comment: I'm in North America, Canada specifically

Comment: I'll see if I can upload a photo or link some photos

Comment: Thanks, @Sterling. I [edit]ed that into your question to make it more obvious for other readers. Not everyone gets through all the comments. Please take the [tour] to get a better idea how this site works and how it's different than most other discussion forums on the internet.

Comment: https://ibb.co/album/KmZS8k

Comment: As far as I can tell, it doesn't need a 120v circuit for lights etc

Comment: @Ecnerwal from the wall to the original oven in the house, has a 4 prong 3 wire red black white plus copper for ground

Comment: @Sterling for your *next* question, note that all of this information would have been good to include in the question itself, as it was important to arriving at the correct answer. I've deleted most of my comments that are no longer needed.

Comment: I wonder how much it costs to maintain this %$#@&*! 120 V/240 V system we have in North America? I am surprised a German made appliance intended for the Norh American market would have a diagram on the back showing 240 V between N and L1. So in these ovens which need only 240 V is the light something other than an incandescent bulb or does it use a 240 V incandescent?

Comment: The writing on the back "220V - 240V" presumably allows some tolerance + or - what percent?

Comment: @JimStewart: I would think an oven light would have to be an incandescent, but the electronics to run a 120V incandescent off 240V would be pretty trivial.  They'd probably fry a CFL or LED bulb that was installed, but then again turning the oven onto 450 would also fry a CFL or LED.

Comment: Look at the oven light, or the manual. Trivial incandescent solution would be two oven lights, Wire them in series when shipping to 120/240V lands, and in parallel when shipping to 240V-only lands. Both will go out at once in 120V lands. Other trivial solution is a 240V bulb, since incandescent bulbs are nearly special order now anyway.

Comment: @JimStewart They're 240 V incandescents. They're specialty bulbs anyway to handle the heat.

Answer (score 13):

So, it's the (German-made) appliance referring to L1, N, and PE in the Euro-market nomenclature.

In North America, a 240V appliance goes to L1 & L2 (North American nomenclature) to get 240V across it. That's both poles of a two-pole breaker that provides 240V.

PE goes to ground.

If the cable or conduit from the wall has a (North American nomenclature) Neutral wire, it's unused and capped off.

You have a 4-wire feed, so the neutral wire is going to be unused here. Black to black, red to red, green to bare copper, cap (isolate/insulate) white.

Comment: It works! Thanks @Ecnerwal, I knew I was over thinking it. Cheers